# Scala convert list of Strings to multiple variables

Tags: string, scala

I'm trying to convert a list of strings to multiple variables so that I can assign attributes to the content of list.

My code:

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
val attributes = Attributes(#SomeAwesomeScalaCode#) 

case class Attributes(input:(String, String, String, String, String, String)) {
val a, b, c, d, e, f = input
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the pattern matching:

```
  val List(a, b, c, d) = List("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

in the case of tuple, just add the braces around the `val` declaration like this:

```
  case class Attributes(input:(String, String, String, String, String, String)) {
     val (a, b, c, d, e, f) = input
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in vanilla Scala. However, the [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library provide some tools to work with tuples generically. The following works:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.syntax.std.traversable._

case class Attributes(input: (String, String, String, String, String, String)) {
  val a, b, c, d, e, f = input
}

object Main extends App {
  val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

  val attributes = list.toHList[String :: String :: String :: String :: String :: String :: HNil].map(hl => Attributes(hl.tupled))

  println(attributes)
}
```

Note that `attributes` is actually `Option[Attributes]` because `List -> HList` conversion may fail if types or length are wrong (not in this particular case, but in general).